# Read Excel with varying number of rows per column to dataframe without NAN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have an excel file that looks like:

[image: sample input]

I would like to read this into pandas dataframe and avoid getting NAN values. The reason I am trying to avoid getting NAN is that later on, I want to create a simple contingency table similar to this

[image: sample output]

and NAN values create issues in this contingency table. Is there any elegant way of doing this without reading columns separately, using value_counts(), and concatenating the series, as below?

```
df_1=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', usecols='A')
df_2=pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', usecols='B')
value_c_1 = df_1.value_counts()
value_c_2 = df_2.value_counts()
pd.concat([value_c_1, value_c_2], axis=1)
```

There must be an elegant way of doing this; my apologies if the answer is so obvious; I searched for it before posting this question.

Comment: why do you need to drop them? value_counts does not count NaN by default

Comment: @gold_cy sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your excel is like following dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['x','y','x','x', '','','',''],
              'B' : ['y', 'x','x','x','x','y','y','x',]})
```

You can try this :

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).loc[['x','y']]
```

Comment: It applies a `pd.value_counts`  to each column. Then I use `.loc` to extract x and y. For the `pd.value_counts` you can check here :https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html